# MySQL: for every item, return ALL subitems with NULL on non-matching ones

Tags: mysql, null, subquery, row, parent

the idea is: "imagine a dictionary".

I have WORDS, and DEFINITIONS.
I have LANGUAGES, and ACTIVE LANGUAGES.

This means that I can have 5 languages, in example, but only three of 'em are active.

So I need to get for every single word in the dictionary, 3 rows, with it's definitions.

So I need this:

```
word BLABLA -> ES: bla
            -> EN: brabra
            -> FR: bleh

word BLIBLI -> ES: NULL
            -> EN: blig
            -> FR: NULL
```

...

As you can see, word BLIBLI in ES and FR has no definitions, and every kind of JOIN I've tried, gives me something like:

```
word BLABLA -> ES: bla
            -> EN: brabra
            -> FR: bleh

word BLIBLI -> EN: blig
```

So, not all the results.
I've tried RIGHT and LEFT JOINS, but nothing works...

I strictly need to get as many lines as active languages exists for every matched word:

Something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM active_languages al
LEFT JOIN word_definitions wd ON(al.language_id = wd.language_id);
```

results in the second example.

But if I just modify a bit the last query with:

```
SELECT *
FROM active_languages al
LEFT JOIN word_definitions wd ON(al.language_id = wd.language_id AND wd.word_id = 1);
```

wich basically adds a word ID on the join, then something like this happens:

```
word BLABLA -> ES: bla
            -> EN: brabra
            -> FR: bleh
```

but of course, just for word qith ID 1.

Then I need to loop through all words (well in fact are going to be a group of matched words). I know this probably could be done via parent query that goes trought all words with WHERE filtering, and having this last query as a subquery with the ID word being linked with parent query. But I don't know how to do that.
It always gives me the error "MySQL error #1054 - Unknown column error"...

What can I do please?

Thanks!

Comment: What I meaned is that by adding an ID to the join, I get the wished result for every word I select there. So In the case of BLIBLI, I get all the three rows, with empty data.

Comment: can you post table definition and data for both tables?

Comment: Did you really try that Right Join? It should work.